# IOS push notification break point

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, apple-push-notifications

I use phone-gap plugin for APN and xcode 5.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

I put a breakpoint at each function in the plugin.
For some reason when i send a push notification not even single break point are hit.

But the notification received on my device.

Any explanation for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things you could check:

Did you set them in in xcode or in the safari debugger? Actually I am not sure if the first option would ever work at all. Have any breakpoints worked in your application?

Is the app running in the foreground when the notification is received? As far as I know, no code is executed on receiving the message if the app is running in the background, so this might also be a reason for not hitting any breakpoints.

Comment: The app is on background.
In Android code run even if application is closed.
I hoped that in IOS too, shame.